# matlab to python coding

Tags: python, matlab

I have this code in MATLAB and I am trying to convert it in Python.

```
 yc(1:45)=-2;
 yc(46:90)=2;
 yc(91:136)=-2;
 yc(137:182)=2;
```

I don't know how to convert it in python thnx for helping me

Comment: What is `yc` and what argument does it take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Direct Equivalent

The direct equivalent, using `numpy` would be:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> yc = np.empty(182)
>>> yc[:45] = -2       # Equivalent to, yc[0:45] = -2
>>> yc[45:90] = 2
>>> yc[90:136] = -2
>>> yc[136:] = 2       # Equivalent to, yc[136:182] = 2
```

Where [`np.empty`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) creates an array with random values, of given shape. Then we proceed to assign different values by accessing in slices.

## Alternate Way

You can also try with [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
>>> yc = np.arange(182)
>>> yc = np.select(condlist=[
                       yc < 45, (45 <= yc) & (yc < 90), 
                       (90 <= yc) & (yc < 136), yc >= 136
                   ],
                   choicelist=[-2, 2, -2, 2])

>>> yc
 
array([-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2,
       -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2,
       -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
        2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
        2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
        2,  2,  2,  2,  2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2,
       -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2,
       -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2,
        2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
        2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
        2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2])
```

Here `np.arange` creates an array with values ranging from 0 to 181 (182 values in total), and we create a new array substituting different values in the array according to different conditions.

Things to keep in mind:

- MATLAB starts indexing from 1, whereas python starts from 0.
- You need to pre-allocated an array in order to assign via slices.

## Helpful Links:

- [Numpy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)
- [Numpy for MATLAB users](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)